# Windows does not allow creating VSS shadow copy on removable USB flash disk, why?

Tags: ntfs, vss

I formatted a 16GB USB flash disk to NTFS and tried to make it VSS available, but failed. I tried to do it on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine, running

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=e:
```

and I got error:

```
Error: The given shadow copy provider does not support shadow copying the specified volume.
```

Can some one tell me why it is not allowed? I thought the only requirement is using NTFS on the volume(partition).

[image]

Comment: Obviously you were mistaken about the requirement.  There is a great deal that Windows does not like putting on removable devices.

Comment: There are ways to make an external removable flash drive, appear not to be removable to Windows, you could try doing that.  I wouldn't because I suspect there is a good reason this isn't supported.